# Objective-C – ShareKit customize Twitter navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Does anyone know how to customize the Twitter navigation bar in ShareKit? (change colors and add image)

Cheers,

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SHKTwitterForm.m add the line given below inside `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

You can tweak this class to customize more.